# Background slideshow picture for conemu

Tags: conemu

Does anyone know a way to get a series of pictures as in a slideshow appearing as a background in ConEmu? Where the next picture is chosen at a given time interval.

Or alternatively is there a way to programatically change the background by writing a script to different pictures such as the following ones?

C:\Users\user\My Pictures\pic1.jpg

C:\Users\user\My Pictures\pic2.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just set up as your background

```
C:\Users\user\My Pictures\pic_.jpg
```

And create a script that will do cyclic copying of fresh image to `pic_.jpg`.